# how to add a chromium browser shortcut to desktop

Tags: raspbian, chromium

I'd like to add a browser shortcut to the Raspberry desktop, have followed an old post (https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=22235)
which suggests creating a text file such as below

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Link
Name=Raspberry Pi website
Comment=The infamous Raspberry Pi computer
Icon=/home/pi/raspberrypi.jpg
URL=http://www.raspberrypi.org
```

I've done this, but when clicking the textfile just the textfile itself opens.  Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved after adding an icon graphic... just creating an empty file with .jpg extension was sufficient.